# Webpage opens well in JSFiddle and SO, but not in Chrome (as single webpage)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

```css
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }

body, html { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

.audio {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6em;
  padding: 0.6em;
  border: 10px solid green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(7, 2fr);
  grid-template-areas: "p s s s s s s s";
}

.audio .play-pause {
  grid-area: p;
}

.audio .svg {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.2em;
  border: 10px solid red;
}

.audio svg {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

#play {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2.7;
  fill: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="audio">
  <div class="play-pause">
    <div class="pause svg">
      <svg id="play" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <polygon points="10 90 90 50 10 10" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is all good, but if I make this into a webpage, the `play-pause` div seems to break out of the grid in Chrome 96. Here is the full code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <style>
    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body,
    html {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .audio {
      width: 100%;
      height: 6em;
      padding: 0.6em;
      border: 10px solid green;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(7, 2fr);
      grid-template-areas: "p s s s s s s s";
    }

    .audio .play-pause {
      grid-area: p;
    }

    .audio .svg {
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0.2em;
      border: 10px solid red;
    }

    .audio svg {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
    }

    #play {
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 2.7;
      fill: transparent;
    }
  </style>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="audio">
    <div class="play-pause">
      <div class="pause svg">
        <svg id="play" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <polygon points="10 90 90 50 10 10" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Just an observation, you are mixing setting grid template columns and grid template areas. Perhaps try without the template areas which I can’t make sense of.

Comment: @AHaworth I used grid areas to have a visual representation of what layout I'm trying to make (which only makes things easy). There is one row with 8 columns. First column is area p and rest are combined into s. Whichever element takes p gets the first column and element with area s gets the 7 columns, though only the first one is relevant here. I hope that that makes things clear.